PyTorch Bounding Box in COCO Format resize issue: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
I'm trying this example
https://lightning.ai/lightning-ai/studios/object-detection-with-pytorch-lightning#full-training-example
And this is the output code of bounding box in the annotation of image size 512X512
bbox = dataset.coco.loadAnns(dataset.ids[2])[0]['bbox']
bbox

Output
[56.172661870503596,
 120.63309352517986,
 10.129496402877699,
 13.812949640287755]

I'm executing the following lines to make sure BB get processed in image processor as well using this code
small = (bbox[:, 2] * bbox[:, 3]) <= (image.size[1] * image.size[0] * 0.001)
 boxes = ops.box_convert(bbox[~small], in_fmt='xywh', out_fmt='xyxy')
 image, annotations = self.image_processor({"image": image, "boxes": boxes})

But in the first line of code, it gives the following error
list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Any idea, why is giving this error?

[mre] please. and complete traceback.
